# How to do an update with Linq, Lambda and EF

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I got this code that I use for User Create.

```
    public static void CreateUser(User user)
    {

            Save<User>(u => u.AddObject(user));

     }

    Save<T>(Action<ObjectSet<T>> func)
       where T : class
    {

        ...

        func(entitySet);

        entitiesContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Now I am trying to write an update method, but it doesn't compile on  `u = user`

```
public static void UpdateUser(User user)
{
        Save<User>(u => u = user);
}
```

How do I update an object?

Comment: It is unwise (and sometimes a plain error) to name a variable and a type the same.

Comment: @Lucero Right that got mixed up when I was posting on SO. Fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the entity is detached from context you can update it as follows.

```
public static void UpdateUser(User user)
{
      Save<User>(u => { 
         u.Attach(user); 
         u.Context.ObjectStateManager
              .ChangeObjectState(user, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
         });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want do it with linq, then you can implement custom generic delegate that should have ref params. For example.

```
public delegate void MyDelegate<T>(ref T x);

 public static void CreateUser(User user)
 {
        Save<User>((ref User u) => u = user));
 }

Save<T>(MyDelegate<ObjectSet<T>> func)
   where T : class
{

    ...

    func(entitySet);

    entitiesContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'MyDelegate<System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet<User>>' because the parameter types do not match the delegate parameter types